# For onchange of the Dropdown list fetch the data from the db with out submitting the form in php

Tags: php

For onchange of the Dropdown list fetch the data from the db with out submitting the form.

I need to check the data according to the selected data of Dropdown list with database(example: `select count(*) from employee`).

That is, Consider Dropdown List has 3 options.
if User selects 2nd option then, function(method) should be called to get the data from the database.
if the Query returns 10 the i need to show some message. but the form should not submity here, until he clicks the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript here to post data to server and return response.
For example you can use jQuery .alax() method when the onchange event of your dropdown is fired.

```
$('#select').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.name/somescript.php',
    data: {item: $this.find('option:selected').val()}
    success: function(xhr){
      // analyze recieved data from server
      if(xhr.responseText == '10')
        alert('some message');
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you @Hck for providing the code, and what is this url: 'http://domain.name/somescript.php', For what reason we should use this

Comment: In this script you are doing the query to DB, and echo responce to client. Then the response will be checked on client side.

Comment: Hi @Hck, should I write the same thing here data: {item: $this.find('option:selected').val()}

Comment: No, you can write any data you want to be transfered to server and then to be accessed in php via $_POST or $_GET etc. Current example transfers a value of chosen option to server, and can be accessed by $_POST['item'] or $_GET['item'] depending on the request method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire off an [XHR](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest) request to a script that would query the DB and return the results for you to display. [Using jQuery to do it is simple](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).